# Does Q "play games" with other species?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

Does Q play games with other species, or is it just humans (and possibly the Calamarain)? Why didn't Q torture the humans (as far as we know) as he did the Calamarain?

Comment: Just saying, a lot of the things Q did to Picard COULD be called "torture," Q was just doing it to an incredibly capable and stoic victim.  Put a dumber, more emotional, more vindictive captain in Picard's place and it may have played out just like the Calamarain.

Comment: Not necessarily dumber. The Hirogen seemed intelligent to me but I can definitely see them seeking revenge on a power-stripped Q.

Comment: Definitely true.  I mean being dumber, more emotional, or more vindictive would each be a path to revenge.  All three wouldn't be necessary at once, but since Picard was smart, stoic, and forgiving, his reactions are probably the exception among Q's playthings.  Also, in relation to your question: didn't they say that a bunch of other species were coming for Q when he became human?  I don't think they named them, but I thought they specifically said that many different species have their own beef with Q, which would imply that he's had many playthings.

Comment: I also remember a reference being made to Q being the "God of Lies" on at least one world

Comment: @JasonBaker From "Q-Less": `VASH: You're the one who almost got me killed on Errikang Seven. And they weren't exactly thrilled to see you on Brax either. What did they call you? The God of Lies?`

Comment: If you consider all Q, including Junior, then we can definitely say that Q do harass other species, as seen in "Q2."

Answer (score 5):

I believe there may be a book with Q messing with other species, however the episode of TNG where Q is stripped of his powers and has many species gunning for him is fair evidence that yes he screws with many species

I believe Picard actually states that Q came to them because he knew that out of all the species or individuals he had messed with, Picard was the only one who would risk himself to protect him.

I don't remember the name of the cloud species thing that actually found Q in that episode if it was the Calamarin Q was going to torture them/it (don't recall off hand if it was one member or a number of members of the race) because he was feeling vindictive at their attempt to harm him. The humans, on the other hand, didn't actually try to hurt Q, they locked him up and he felt some pain, perhaps bruised his ego, but he honestly didn't expect to be treated like royalty when he appeared on the Enterprise's bridge.