# Did Q torment anyone else besides the crew of the Enterprise, Voyager, and DS9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-q

I was surprised to be reminded that while Q appeared many times on *The Next Generation* and *Voyager*, he also appeared in one *Deep Space 9* episode "Q-less".

Obviously, this is pretty lucky that he happens to have interacted with exactly the three crews we have TV shows about.

We know he interacted in the past with the El-Aurians (Guinan), the Borg, and any number of single-reference species.    But the obvious ones I can think of are throwaway references or backstory.

Are there any canon references to Q interacting in a more concrete way, in contemporary times with a major race (from our point of view) such as a Federation member, another Federation ship, the Klingons, Romulans, Ferengi, etc?

Comment: I've read in answers on here before that it was possible that he could have but not as Q. Since he appears wearing a Starfleet uniform to the members of the mentioned crews it's possible he appears to other species/characters as something the would find familiar. So it could be the same being pestering someone else but they might not report him as looking the same and he may nto go by the same name.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68482/does-q-play-games-with-other-species

Comment: @IanAuld:   OK, that's a justification.   It doesn't mean there couldn't be a reference to that interaction.   Also, I would add, he appeared as a N_Soong-type android and as a Bajoran waiter and was still recognizable.   Plus he appears to use the name Q elsewhere too (Guinan).

Comment: He warns Q-Jr. not to mess with the Borg.

Comment: I think not. Q's reason for messing with humanity is that the continuum saw them as being the race with the most potential of current races and that they were squandering that potential (although why they could not just travel to the future and know the answer baffles me)

Comment: @user2399216:   That wouldn't explain Q not interacting with other ships or humans on planets.

Comment: @IanAuld: ugh, not [that old trick](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Devil's_Due_(episode)).

Comment: Depends on whether you consider Star Trek: Borg to be cannon.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Maybe Q has good taste, and so we only make Star Trek shows about crews that he likes.

Comment: On shapeshifting/illusions:  [Ponies](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Discord#Production_and_development).

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR: Not really. After all, most lesser species are so... dull.**

---

The entity known as [**Q**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q) is known - especially in the [Q Continuum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q_Continuum) - as a troublemaker who enjoys messing with lesser species, often tormenting them in the name of "fun".

[image]

Out-of-universe, the reasons are obvious - we are only seeing the crews which are a focus of the shows, so naturally it's THEIR experiences with Q that we are witness to. However, there are valid in-universe reasons why these encounters happen.

### Federation Encounters

That said, he initially encountered the [NCC-1701-D](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-D)) as they were - at that time - the furthest Federation vessel know to the Q, and were therefore chosen as an example of the Federation's exploratory & adventurous nature. This initial encounter impressed Q, and he quickly became somewhat infatuated with the crew, especially [Captain Picard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard), whom he came to view as something akin to a beloved pet.

> "... in all the universe, you're the closest thing I have to a friend,
>   Jean-Luc." -- Q; [TNG S03E13](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deja_Q_(episode))

Q's visit to [DS9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9) was not due to any interest in the station or crew, but instead on the woman [Vash](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vash), who had returned to the Alpha Quadrant via the [Bajoran Wormhole](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran_wormhole) and therefore found herself on DS9. Q attempted to play with [Benjamin Sisko](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Benjamin_Sisko) as he had Picard, but quickly learned that Sisko was simply "no fun" to play with.

The [USS Voyager](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Voyager) only got the attention of the Q Continuum after accidentally releasing [an exiled member](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quinn) of the Continuum from the comet into which he had been imprisoned. He quickly found a new, unsuspecting plaything in [Captain Janeway](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kathryn_Janeway), however, whose stern manner reminded him very much of Picard.

Beyond the encounters with Picard & the other crews, Q had very little interest in either Earth OR humanity. He and the Continuum in general certainly had very little interest in the current cultures on Earth, instead seeing humanity only for its potential in the eons to come.

> "An abysmal place, Earth. Oh, don't get me wrong. A thousand years ago
>   it had character: the Crusades, the Spanish Inquisition, Watergate.
>   Now it's just mind-numbingly dull." Q; [DS9 1x07](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q-Less_(episode))

### Other Encounters

We know from various episodes that Q had tormented other races, not only once but several times - certainly enough to garner a negative reputation throughout the galaxy.

When he became powerless and sought refuge on the Enterprise-D, it became obvious that numerous races hated Q enough to hunt him down while he was vulnerable. The [Calamarain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Calamarain) were the first to arrive, but Q seemed fairly certain that others would be coming as well.

For instance, Q had tormented the inhabitants of [Brax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Brax_(planet)) enough that he was known in their culture as the "God of Lies". This would seem to indicate a definite pattern of behavior, rather than one or two encounters on the planet.

Comment: Although we never see it on screen, the fact that it is *mentioned* on screen that Q is known as the 'God of Lies' to the Brax (Braxians?) should say that yes, he has harassed other people. Not to even mention the Calamarain et al.

Comment: @Xantex : The OP was looking for tormenting of members of major races in contemporary times, not of "single-reference species".

Comment: How is this an answer to the question that has been asked?  The OP already mentioned TNG, Voyager, DS9, so why dedicate four paragraphs to those?  The OP didn't ask to be explained why Q encounters those three groups.  The OP asked for evidence of torment "in contemporary times with a major race" and specifically ruled out "single-reference species" and "throwaway references".  There's a lot of content in this answer, but nothing that has anything to do with the question.  The graphic is fine, but it's a -1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

**There is no evidence in any of the television series or films to suggest that Q harassed other Starfleet or Federation vessels or tormented Romulans, Klingons, Ferengi, or other members of major Alpha and Beta quadrant powers in contemporary times**.

He made a passing reference in *Voyager* (["The Q and the Grey"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/306.htm)) to having ruled out a Klingon targ and the Romulan Empress as potential mothers for his child, but there is no evidence that he directly approached or harassed either a targ or the Empress.

**Note:** There are various throwaway references to Q tormenting minor species in canon, and there are various encounters with the Q in the extended universe, but I chose not to comment on these based on the wording of the OP's question.