# Were the other Alpha-Beta quadrant powers aware of the Q?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-q

We know that the Federation, at least the high ranking officials and Starfleet, were aware of the Q as a species but also "De-Lancie-Q" in particular. The thing is, while Q was quite fascinated with humanity as a whole and Picard in particular, I find it hard to believe he didn't meddle in the affairs of other species as much.

Also, we can surmise that other species elsewhere in the galaxy, such as the El-Aurians (at least some of them) and the Borg (post Best of Both Worlds), knew Q as well.

So, my question is: how about the other Alpha/Beta quadrant powers such as the Romulans/Klingons/Ferengi/Cardassians/Breen? ***Had they directly encountered the Q or were they at least aware of them?*** By this I mean first-hand experience and not leaked reports etc, that could be attributed to misinformation and so on.

Canon but also expanded universe stories are acceptable.

Comment: Every captain in Starfleet received a briefing on Q; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133423/20774 Is that sufficient for you? I would imagine that given that there are thousands of ships on the fleet, that sort of info would leak to every major power with even the most cursory intelligence-gathering capability. ..

Comment: In case of the Borg the question would be weither they could even perceive the Q as such rather than a strange anomaly moving their cube (or worse: it being corrupted data).

Comment: @Valorum These briefings were only given to Captains and possibly other high ranking officials. Also, even if this info leaked to other major powers, it would be easy to attribute it to misinformation etc. Anyway, who would believe stories about god-like entities that can fling you half way across the Galaxy with a snap of their fingers? I'll edit the question to make it more specific.

Comment: So you're asking if the other powers had ever *encountered* a Q?

Comment: I guess that's a good way of saying it. I'll edit my question again to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: EVen with the briefings only being for captains, the regular staff wasn't put off much when Sisko OPENLY talked about the Q.

Comment: Q does tell Janeway that he used his omnipotence to impress females of every species. Assuming that Q is telling the truth here (and I accept it as true, since nothing in canon contradicts it), then this means that nearly every humanoid species in the universe has encountered Q. Also, this may include the Companion, which strangely was concluded to be female, though probably not other energy beings such as the Douwd or Trelane's species, which are likely without gender. Notable humanoid exceptions would include the genderless J'naii.

Comment: Hey, is this similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100809/did-q-torment-anyone-else-besides-the-crew-of-the-enterprise-voyager-and-ds9?rq=1  I'm not trying to kill this question but it seems to have gotten edited to within an inch of this other question.

Comment: @Xplodotron That question asks if Q tormented any other species, while I'm asking if other species were aware of the Q. Not to be pedantic, but they're different things actually :)  In any case, my question is already dead Jim!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

In DS9 episode 1x07 "[Q-Less](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q-Less_(episode))", Q appears inside the Deep Space 9 station, where he interacts with various characters and is seen in Quark's Bar by the guests, especially during a fistfight with Benjamin Sisko.

Besides being Deep Space 9 a station known to be frequented by members of many different species that can potentially have seen him or directly interacted with him, we explicitly see that some **Bajorians** and Quark, a **Ferengi**, clearly see him during this scene at the bar; his flamboyant attitude and behavior does not seem to cause too much surprise, it seems likely that those characters are aware of who he is.

Comment: The implication is that their lack of surprise is because Q has made them into audience puppets.

Comment: He merely made them disappear and reappear again, like in other similar situations in TNG, where we know that the crew know him well. Besides this, the question was " Had they directly encountered the Q or were they at least aware of them? By this I mean first-hand experience and not leaked reports etc, that could be attributed to misinformation and so on." and the answer is yes. I don't understand this downvoting everytime on legit answers.

Comment: It's not really clear what the crowd understand about what's going on. They're in a cafe, then suddenly in a boxing ring cheering the captain as he fights a man they don't know